# Android Java error:null pointer exception can't see why?

Tags: java, android

Hi I have an app written that goes from a login page, to another activity with a progress bar, then to another activity with a tab host. If I get rid of the loading page and go from login to the tab host works fine, but if I try to go from login to loading the app stops and says 'Unfortunately application has stopped.' I have checked the logcat and see that there is a null pointer error for the Loading page, but I can't see why. In the intent to go from login to loading I call loading correctly, and the set content view in Loading matches its xml loading_main. Here is my code below, thannks:

Main login activity:
    package com.example.loginscreen;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText  username=null;
   private EditText  password=null;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   public void login(View view){
      if(username.getText().toString().equals("mara") && 
      password.getText().toString().equals("mara")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Loading.class)); 
       }    
   else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
      counter--;
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      if(counter==0){
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

   }

}
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Loading activity:
    package com.example.loginscreen;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Loading extends Activity {

    Button btnStartProgress;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener( // <== This is line 33
                new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            // prepare for a progress bar dialog
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            progressBar.setMessage("Searching for Driver Card...");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.show();

            //reset progress bar status
            progressBarStatus = 0;

            //reset filesize
            fileSize = 0;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                  // process some tasks
                  progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

                  // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  // Update the progress bar
                  progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                   });
                }

                // driver card is found
                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                   // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // close the progress bar dialog
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                 }
              }
               });
            startActivity(new Intent(Loading.this,LinkTabs.class));

               }

                });

        }
    // file download simulator
        public int doSomeTasks() {

            while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

                fileSize++;

                if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
                } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
                } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                    return 30;
                }

            }

            return 100;

        }

     }
```

Activity LinkTabs to link all tabs in tab host:
    package com.example.loginscreen;

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LinkTabs extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.link_main);

        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // First tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.overview))
          .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Second tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage2.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage2 = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage2")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.card_summary))
          .setContent(intentApple);

        // Third tab
        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage3.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage3 = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage3")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.details))
          .setContent(intentWindows);


        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage2);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage3);


        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

}
```

Tab activities:
package com.example.loginscreen;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Overview");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}



package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Card Summary");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}



package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage3 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Details");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

Here are the xml files:
     //activity_main.xml

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        tools:ignore="TextFields" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tranzlogo1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="@string/attempts"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="@string/Login" />

</RelativeLayout>


 //fragment_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tranzlogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:src="@drawable/overview"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</RelativeLayout>


//link_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tranzlogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:src="@drawable/overview"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</RelativeLayout>


//loading_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is loading_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the mainfest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.loginscreen"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="10"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

      <activity
         android:name="com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
          >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomePage" />
    <activity android:name=".HomePage2" />
    <activity android:name=".HomePage3" />
    <activity android:name=".Loading"/>
    <activity android:name=".LinkTabs"/>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

And the logcat output:

```
06-20 10:22:15.289: W/dalvikvm(29524): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cca318)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginscreen/com.example.loginscreen.Loading}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at com.example.loginscreen.Loading.addListenerOnButton(Loading.java:33)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at com.example.loginscreen.Loading.onCreate(Loading.java:26)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
06-20 10:22:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(29524):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post `loading_main.xml`

Comment: does R.layout.loading_main contains button1?

Comment: you should post only relevant snippet of code.

Comment: There is no button1 in loading main That is the reason of your Null pointer!

Comment: Paste too much code wont help you.
Please tell what exactly the issue. you are accessing null values so you are getting  nullpointer error.
Please put log values and detect worng code and show that much code only.

Comment: @ user3478524: When referencing exceptions with line numbers, always point out the line the exception refers to when posting the code. I've counted lines in your second code block and *think* I've identified the correct line, but you should double-check that and use the "edit" link if necessary to fix it.

Comment: ^^ I counted em too :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have referenced in Your LoadingMain activity the following layout with setContentView:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.loading_main);
```

But this Layout does not have any button1. Instead, You are trying to reference a button from another layout, from activity_main.xml

```
   btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

This button1 is inside the activity_main.xml and You cannot reference a button in a layout that is not attached per setContentView. So What You have to do is, add a button to the loading_main.xml, BUT, don´t give it the same id like in the activity main "button1". Sure, it works, to give same ids as long as the right layout is referenced, but id´s should be unique. If the button in the activity_layout should remain, give the id for your button inside loading_main.xml another name, maybe android:id="@+id/loading_main_button_1".

Comment: Hi thanks I was wondering about referencing buttons from other layouts/activityies. I don't want any buttons to be visible in the loading activity with tht progress bar, but rather for the button in the login activity to move to the loading activity activate the progress bar and move on to the tab host activity. Will your suggestion accomplish this?

Comment: then You just have to delete the buttons that You don´t want from the activities and put it only inside the login screen. Also, delete all references inside the activities and only reference the button inside Your login screen

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the error is in xml, you have not added the button here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try adding the following in your loading_main.xml

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The complete thing should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="413dp"
    android:layout_height="382dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks I was wondering about referencing buttons from other layouts/activityies. I don't want any buttons to be visible in the loading activity with tht progress bar, but rather for the button in the login activity to move to the loading activity activate the progress bar and move on to the tab host activity. Will your suggestion accomplish this?

Comment: I am not aware of the complexity of your problem, but the solution to your Null Pointer exception lies in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`NullPointerExcception`**

it causes because using null object or not defining value to object.

In **`Loading.java`** you have used

```
setContentView(R.layout.loading_main);
```

that don't have `button1`

**add `button1`** in `loading_main.xml` it or **Change layout** in `setContentView(R.layout.other_layout);`